# SQL Server 2014 SP1 installation failure - bug in SSIS_hotfix_install.sql

Tags: service-pack, sql-server-2014

Installation of [SQL Server 2014 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3018269) fails if you have as SSIS Catalog on your server. After that, server does not start. Rebuilding system databases did not help (not sure, maybe because system databases were not actually corrupted, hence they were not really rebuilt maybe).

There's a bug in the script SSIS_hotfix_install.sql which ships with SP1 on line 3188:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_internal_object_parameters_inc] ON [internal].[object_parameters]
```

They used a 2-part name for the table while the script which is supposed to upgrade SSISDB is executed in the master database.

The script can by default be found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Install` , but apparently they do not take it from there for execution upon server startup.
They probably take it from `sqlscriptupgrade.dll` found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn`.
Does anybody know how to bypass execution of that script and get server to start?

Comment: Apparently you rushed the gun a bit. The service pack has since been removed from the downloads list and [reports are coming in that it breaks](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2015/04/15/sql-server-2014-service-pack-1-is-now-available.aspx) if you have [an SSIS Catalog present](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/04/breaking-news-dont-install-sql-server-2014-sp1/).

Comment: Yes, was eager to install it hoping to fix another old bug which has been pain in the arse for a long time. To my credit, I did test it on a staging server, but there was no SSISDB on it :). I have now found partial workaround using system restore. Unfortunately system databases were not rolled back by it, so looking out for problems. Already see that SSIS packages execution fails, but engine, RS and AS appear working normally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start SQL Server with [trace flag 902](http://www.sqlserverf1.com/starting-sql-server-using-t902-trace-flag-to-skip-the-script-upgrade/). This will bypass the execution of upgrade script.

> 1. Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 or the highest
>      version installed -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration
>      Manager
> 2. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, click SQL Server Services.
> 3. In the right pane, right-click SQL Server (), and then click Properties.
> 4. On the Startup Parameters tab, in the Specify a startup parameter box, type the parameter (in this case the trace flag -T902), and
>      then click Add. You will now see the parameters similar to below SQL
>      Server Istance Startup Parameters SQL Server Istance Startup
>      Parameters
> 5. Click OK.
> 6. Restart the Database Engine.
> 7. Connect to SQL Server instance from SQL Server Management Studio and take corrective actions to resolve the errors causing script
>      upgrade to fail.
> 8. Now finally remove the -T902 trace flag from SQL Server Configuration manager
> 9. Restart SQL Server Instance
> 10. Verify Errorlog to make sure script upgrade finished successfully

Then, afterwards, manually execute the SSIS_hotfix_install.sql script (after having added `SSISDB.` in line 3188).

Comment: Added some documentation + information, feel free to rollback if you don't  approve.

Comment: Thanks, will try tomorrow. Was looking for exactly this kind of solution, but by now have already rolled back installation and will have to test on another server.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the suggested procedure - it did not work which was somewhat foreseeable. Upon subsequent startup, after removing -T902 trace flag, the server tries to execute the same script compiled into dll (see above), which I cannot modify. The script is dumb in not detecting that the changes contained in it are already applied. A dirty workaround which I could think of is creating that table in master database to allow script to build the index on it and succeed.
I tested this and it worked.
The whole procedure:

1. After failed installation set -T902 startup parameter.
2. Execute the following code on your server:

`USE master;
GO
create schema internal;
go
CREATE TABLE [internal].[object_parameters](
    [parameter_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [project_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [project_version_lsn] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [object_type] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [object_name] nvarchar NOT NULL,
    [parameter_name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [parameter_data_type] nvarchar NOT NULL,
    [required] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [sensitive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [description] nvarchar NULL,
    [design_default_value] [sql_variant] NULL,
    [default_value] [sql_variant] NULL,
    [sensitive_default_value] varbinary NULL,
    [base_data_type] nvarchar NULL,
    [value_type] char NOT NULL,
    [value_set] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [referenced_variable_name] nvarchar NULL,
    [validation_status] char NOT NULL,
    [last_validation_time] datetimeoffset NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Object_Parameters] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [parameter_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]`

4. Remove the -T902 startup parameter and restart server
5. Clean up master database by executing

`use master;
drop table [internal].[object_parameters];
drop schema internal;`

6. Execute SSIS_hotfix_install.sql manually after correcting line 3188 as detailed above.
7. Restart server.

The reason for executing corrected SSIS_hotfix_install.sql at the end of the procedure is to prevent the buggy script embedded in dll from dropping the index upon subsequent startup, before SQL Server considers upgrade as completed successfully.

Comment: Just after posting it found similar workaround suggested by microsoft: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2015/04/16/sql-server-2014-service-pack-1-has-released.aspx. They missed however that the index IX_internal_object_parameters_inc would be missing in SSISDB after following their procedure because it would have been created on the fake table in master database.

Comment: I've addressed that: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/info-sql-server-2014-service-pack-1-snafu/